# Smart Notification Window under Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

I am developing an application for Mac OS X. In this application, I need to implement "smart notification window". What I mean by this term.

Here some screenshots:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: ScreenShot2]

In the app I develop, such "smart notification" will be appear under system bar icon.
If you work on a Mac you might notice a similar windows.

[image: Screenshot3]

Does anybody has some code tutorial or examples of such "windows" draw.

Working in XCode, Cocoa Environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See MAAttachedWindow from Matt Gemmel:

http://mattgemmell.com/source

You'll have to scroll down a bit...

[image]